# Draw Navigation Drawer behind StatusBar but not AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to draw my NavigationView behind status bar but my Appbar also shows behind it, on collapse. How can I stop appbar to show behind status bar?

**values-21 styles:**

```
<style name="AppThemeTransparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_recycler"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true" />


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: try giving elevation to your root element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be duplicate to ["Hidden" Toolbar visible under status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164337/hidden-toolbar-visible-under-status-bar)

Try move android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from CoordinatorLayout to DrawerLayout like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried searching for it but couldn't find that answer. Blame my poor googling skills

Comment: @Sourabh  : ) I tried searching this problem for a whole day and couldn't find answer either. Sometime this kind of small problem really drives people crazy.